# Material-ui custom the default clear button on input search type

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, frontend, react-component

I would like to know if it's possible to change the color of the default clear button of search type Input in the material.

I'm talking about this 'X':

[image]

Here my jsx:

```
<InputBase
  placeholder="Search..."
  type="search"
  onChange={(e) => handleChange(filterChoiceRef.current, e)}
  autoFocus={true}
  size="large"
/>
```

I can do a custom one if it's not possible but I hope it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `InputAdornments` and pass the color property -
[image]

Working code sandbox here - https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-8tbo4?file=/demo.js