# How to style TextField clear button?

Tags: material-ui

I have seen only [one post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61247890/material-ui-custom-the-default-clear-button-on-input-search-type) about the same question, but it doesn't seem to work. Doing it the way that the only answer suggests just adds an extra clear button to the text field instead of styling the existing one. What is the class name for the close icon? I think that is the only thing that I'd need to be able to style it, but MUI is pretty bad at telling what the class names are...